# Grid in the center of BorderLayout

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager, grid-layout

i have been trying to make a 2x2 grid in the dead center of this but i cant.either the grid will cover the rest or it will fit but i will be able to see only the last button..

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Buttons extends JFrame
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Example 1");
        frame.setSize(400,200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JButton b1 = new JButton("TOP");
        JButton b2 = new JButton("LEFT");
        JButton b3 = new JButton("RIGHT");
        JButton b4 = new JButton("BOTTOM");

        frame.add(b1, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.add(b2, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        frame.add(b3, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        frame.add(b4, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);



        JPanel grid = new JPanel( new GridLayout(0, 2) );
        JPanel wrapper = new JPanel();
        wrapper.add( grid );    
        frame.add(wrapper, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton bb1 = new JButton("1");
        JButton bb2 = new JButton("2");
        JButton bb3 = new JButton("3");
        JButton bb4 = new JButton("4");


        grid.add( bb1 );
        grid.add( bb2 );
        grid.add( bb3 );
        grid.add( bb4 );  

        frame.setVisible(true);       

    }
    private JPanel frame;
    private JButton b1,b2,b3,b4,bb1,bb2,bb3,bb4;
}
```

the 4 extra buttons have been added but i would like to remove the space in the center

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a GridBagLayout on the main panel and a GridLayout on the child panel:

```
JPanel grid = new JPanel( new GridLayout(0, 2) );
grid.add( b1 );
grid.add( b2 );
grid.add( b3 );
grid.add( b4 );

frame.setLayout( new GridBagLayout() );
frame.add(grid, new GridBagConstraints());
```

The other approach is to use the BorderLayout, but then you will need a wrapper panel so the grid panel doesn't grow:

```
JPanel grid = new JPanel( new GridLayout(0, 2) );
grid.add( b1 );
grid.add( b2 );
grid.add( b3 );
grid.add( b4 );

JPanel wrapper = new JPanel();
wrapper.add( grid );    
frame.add(wrapper, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Edit:

We thought you wanted the buttons at their preferred size and centered. The wrapper panel was added to prevent the buttons from changing size.

If you want the buttons in the center to grow/shrink as the frame size is changed, then you don't need the wrapper panel:

```
 //frame.add(wrapper, BorderLayout.CENTER);
 frame.add(grid, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer,the first method didnt quite workd it moved all the buttons in the center(probably i made i mistake) but the second one worked but there is one tiny problem

[link]http://imgur.com/BJzCShL)

Comment: @GiannisPerpirakis Use the second option, but change the layout to `wrapper.setLayout(new GridBagLayout())`

Comment: sory could you be more specific because i am very new to java..this is the part that i added




JPanel grid = new JPanel( new GridLayout(0, 2) );
        JPanel wrapper = new JPanel();
        wrapper.add( grid );    
        frame.add(wrapper, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        JButton bb1 = new JButton("1");
        JButton bb2 = new JButton("2");
        JButton bb3 = new JButton("3");
        JButton bb4 = new JButton("4");
        
        
        grid.add( bb1 );
        grid.add( bb2 );
        grid.add( bb3 );
        grid.add( bb4 );

Comment: @GiannisPerpirakis, The image you posted doesn't match the code you posted. The image has 8 buttons, the code has 4 buttons. Don't post code in a comment as the code is not readable. Update your question to show the current code causing the problem. The suggestion is that the wrapper panel should use a GridBagLayout because a GridBagLayout will automatically center components in the space available.

Comment: i updated the code..in the image the panel to left is the one i want to make and the other is the current

Comment: oh thanks now i understand,its my fault that i didnt make you understand..now i understand the difference between those two methods you provided.Thnaks!